# How to fix the dropdown position issue in ie?

Tags: html, css

[image: IE dropdown]

[image]

In IE the position of the options is overlay on the selectbox, but in Chrome it is working fine, is there any trick to make it work like in chrome?
Thanks.

Comment: there is no way to answer this questions with the given information. Give us some code/example or anything that we can work with

Comment: here fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/7bnoq156/

Comment: Just some extra info: you can make ie work as any other browser using this http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: There is a lot of missing informations for example : which IE version. Also, this is almost impossible the dropdown overlay the field with a plain `select`...

Comment: oh, you're talking about the "standard" select-box, my bad. I don't think you can change the overlay position of that, you may want to use a custom one if it's really this important

Answer (score 0):

the dropdown cannot be styled on any browser including IE.

You could create a custom dropdown menu with [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/) .